# Cauchy Problem (Waves with a Source)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

> Solve: $$u_{tt}=c^2u_{xx}+x t,\quad u(x,0)=0, \quad u_t(x,0)=0$$

The final answer should be $u=xt^3/6$. I keep getting $xt^3/2$.

How I did the problem:
1/2[phi(x)+phi(-x)]+1/2c int(x+ct,x-ct, 0) dy +1/2c int(0,t)int(x+c(t-s),x-c(t-s), xt) dxds
=(xt)int(t,0, t-s) ds
=xt[t^2-1/2t^2-0]
=1/2xt^3

Sorry if this is hard to read. First time using this forum for help and not sure how to type everything out on here yet. Any help is appreciated. I have been stuck on it for weeks.

Comment: As it stands the question is very difficult to read. Please reformat the remaining parts of the question with [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the general non-homogeneous equation
$$u_{tt} - c^2 u_{xx} = f(x,t),\quad u(x,0) = \phi(x), \quad u_t(x,0) = \psi(x)$$
Is given by:
$$u(x,t) = \frac{\phi(x-ct)+\phi(x+ct)}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \int_{x-ct}^{x+ct} \psi(s)ds +\frac{1}{2c} \int_{0}^{t}\int_{x-c(t-s)}^{x+c(t-s)}f(r,s)dsdr$$
In your case, $\psi = \phi = 0$, so that:
$$u(x,t) = \frac{1}{2c} \int_{0}^{t}\int_{x-c(t-s)}^{x+c(t-s)}rs\ dsdr = 
\int_{0}^{t} sx(t-s) ds = \frac{xt^3}{6}$$